# Trouble with Flatten[]

Tags: list-manipulation

I made this function:

```
f[g_] := Table[{ToExpression[ToString[x] <> ToString[n]], 1, 3}, {n, 1, g}]
```

When I evaluate the function with some g (say 8), I'll have this output:

```
{{x1, 1, 3}, {x2, 1, 3}, {x3, 1, 3}, {x4, 1, 3}, {x5, 1, 3}, {x6, 1, 3}, {x7, 1, 3}, {x8, 1, 3}}
```

When I add flatten to the function:

```
f[g_] := Flatten[Table[{ToExpression[ToString[x] <> ToString[n]], 1, 3}, {n, 1, g}]]
```

I'll have:

```
{x1, 1, 3, x2, 1, 3, x3, 1, 3, x4, 1, 3, x5, 1, 3, x6, 1, 3, x7, 1, 3, x8, 1, 3}
```

When I actually want:

```
{x1, 1, 3}, {x2, 1, 3}, {x3, 1, 3}, {x4, 1, 3}, {x5, 1, 3}, {x6, 1, 3}, {x7, 1, 3}, {x8, 1, 3}
```

I have also tried to use the `Flatten[]` with a level:

```
f[g_] := Flatten[Table[{ToExpression[ToString[x] <> ToString[n]], 1, 3}, {n, 1, g}], 1]
```

But I was unable to do it. What's happening? I could do it with string manipulation, but I guess there might be a way for `Flatten[]` to work.

I'm trying to do this:

```
ArrayPlot[Table[RandomChoice[{q1, q2, q3} -> Range[1, 3]], {q1, 1, 3}, {q2, 1, 3}, {q3, 1, 3}], Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> Black]
```

Where the result of the function is going to replace the `{q1, 1, 3}, {q2, 1, 3}, {q3, 1, 3}`.

Comment: What you want is `Sequence` not `Flatten`.

Comment: With an `Evaluate` thrown in to stop `Table` from complaining.

Comment: I naively learned to *go down* some levels on a list with `Flatten`.

Comment: This is the output: `Sequence[{{x1, 1, 3}, {x2, 1, 3}, {x3, 1, 3}, {x4, 1, 3}, {x5, 1, 3}, {x6, 1, 3}, {x7, 1, 3}, {x8, 1, 3}}]`

Comment: Not _quite_ as simple as I implied, but close. You want to replace the `Head` of your list with `Sequence`, so you want to `Apply` `Sequence` to `Table`, e.g. `Sequence @@ Table[...]`.

Comment: let me put it in proper answer form ...

Comment: Just curious...Why do you want output in the form of a sequence? What do you plan to do with it? Display it? Use it as arguments to another function?...?

Comment: @DavidCarraher I want to do [this](http://pastebin.com/43TM8KXb). I made these functions, now I can make a bigger function that's a little more generalist. But it's still not working properly.

Comment: From what I can tell, it would have been better to leave the output in a list, which can be further processed very easily.

Answer (score 7):

`Flatten` only restructures the internals of an expression. What you want is to replace the `Head` of the expression with `Sequence`. So, change your definition of `f` to

```
f[g_] := Sequence @@ Table[{ToExpression[ToString[x] <> ToString[n]], 1, 3}, {n, 1, g}]
```

Where `Apply` (`@@`) is used to change the `Head` from `List` to `Sequence`. Now, to use it within another `Table`, you need to `Evaluate` it:

```
Table[..., Evaluate[ f[...] ]]
```

This is because `Table` has the `HoldAll` attribute.

**Edit**:
Alternatively, leave the definition of `f` as you have it, but move the `Sequence` into the outer `Table`, as follows:

```
Table[..., Evaluate[ Sequence @@ f[...] ] ]
```